# How can I simplify and format this function?

Tags: python-3.x, split, simplify

So I have this messy code where I wanted to get every word from frankenstein.txt, sort them alphabetically, eliminated one and two letter words, and write them into a new file.

```
def Dictionary():

    d = []
    count = 0

    bad_char = '~!@#$%^&*()_+{}|:"<>?\`1234567890-=[]\;\',./ '
    replace = ' '*len(bad_char)
    table = str.maketrans(bad_char, replace)

    infile = open('frankenstein.txt', 'r')
    for line in infile:
        line = line.translate(table)
        for word in line.split():
            if len(word) > 2:
                d.append(word)
                count += 1
    infile.close()
    file = open('dictionary.txt', 'w')
    file.write(str(set(d)))
    file.close()

Dictionary()
```

How can I simplify it and make it more readable and also how can I make the words write vertically in the new file (it writes in a horizontal list):

```
abbey
abhorred
about
etc....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few improvements below:

```
from string import digits, punctuation

def create_dictionary():

    words = set()

    bad_char = digits + punctuation + '...' # may need more characters
    replace = ' ' * len(bad_char)
    table = str.maketrans(bad_char, replace)

    with open('frankenstein.txt') as infile:
        for line in infile:
            line = line.strip().translate(table)
            for word in line.split():
                if len(word) > 2:
                    words.add(word)

    with open('dictionary.txt', 'w') as outfile:
        outfile.writelines(sorted(words)) # note 'lines'
```

A few notes:

- follow [the style guide](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)
- [`string`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html) contains constants you can use to provide the "bad characters";
- you never used `count` (which was just `len(d)` anyway);
- use the `with` context manager for file handling; and
- using a `set` from the start prevents duplicates, but they aren't ordered (hence `sorted`).

Answer (score 0):

Using *re* module.

```
import re

words = set()

with open('frankenstein.txt') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        words.extend([x for x in re.split(r'[^A-Za-z]*', line) if len(x) > 2])

with open('dictionary.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.writelines(sorted(words))
```

From *r'[^A-Za-z]*'* in *re.split*, replace 'A-Za-z' with the characters which you want to include in dictionary.txt.